# 2 pole single phase induction motor appears to have starting capacitor permanently connected (no centrifugal switch)

Tags: capacitor, induction-motor, single-phase

I am trying to repair and rewire an AC induction motor from a small  compressor. From what I can tell it's a 24 slot, 2 pole single phase induction motor that has main coil and starting coil. The wires for both coils are 24 AWG but the main coil has twice as many loops and the wires appear to be doubled up (A pair of 2 wires connect to power on main coil and a single wire pair for the start coil). There is a thermal overload box connected inline to both the start coil and main coil but what I wasn't expecting is what looks like a start capacitor connected directly from mains to the start coil, no centrifugal switches or timers. This compressor has a low duty cycle but it must run for longer than is healthy for a start capacitor when building pressure.

[image: Capacitor]

It looks like a start capacitor to me because it's not in an oil filled tin but could this be a run capacitor and there is no start capacitor?

What am I missing?

Comment: There is no start capacitor, just run capacitor as you have correctly discovered, so what?

Comment: You've got a PSC motor - https://circuitglobe.com/permanent-split-capacitor-psc-motor.html  The secondary winding is better called an auxiliary rather than a start winding, since it contributes to the field continuously during operation.

Comment: I was just worried that I was missing something and didn't want the start capacitor to go pop. It really doesn't feel like it's oil filled and I've read that run capacitors are in a metal case and this one is plastic.

Comment: I suspect that technology has marched on, and either they've figured out how to make a plastic-cased oil-filled cap, or they've figured out some alternative to an oil-filled cap (possibly the whole thing potted in plastic).  Or, it's a cheap compressor and they figure you won't be able to find them when it breaks (not that I'm, like, cynical or anything).

Comment: Thanks @PhilG, I hadn't heard of that type of motor, this is exactly the type of info I came here for!

Comment: Run caps come in both oil-filled metal and dry plastic case forms, but you'll notice that they're substantially larger in size for a given capacitance than a start cap, since they're continuously rated.

Comment: At only 25 uF, it's a run cap.